# Why was the constructor interface of std::vector changed with C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why was the default argument removed with the new standard? Often I constructed a vector variable like this: `std::vector<my_pod_struct> buf(100)`. I guess I would get an compiler error with a C++11 compiler.

```
explicit vector( size_type count,
                 const T& value = T(),                   /* until C++11 */
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
         vector( size_type count,
                 const T& value,                         /* since C++11 */
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Comment: Did you miss the new constructor `explicit vector( size_type count );`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Before, when you wrote `std::vector<T> buf(100);` you would get one `T` default constructed, and then that instance would be copied over to one hundred slots in the vector.

Now, when you write `std::vector<T> buf(100);`, it will use another constructor: `explicit vector( size_type count );`. This will default-construct one hundred `T`s. It's a slight difference, but an important one.

The new single-argument constructor doesn't require the type `T` to be copyable. This is important because now types can be movable and not copyable.

Comment: +1 when designing generic algorithms, it's easy to let some extra requirements sneak in and not even realize it. The CopyConstructible here is a perfect example of something not so obvious at first glance.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's why we want concepts! ;)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Definitely!

Answer (score 3):

You won't , there is now separate constructor for your use case:

```
explicit vector(size_type n);
```