# What is 2D vector construction breaking change in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

while reading answer to [one question on MS Connect site](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/691756/std-make-pair-error-in-vc11) I noticed the following part of the reply:

> This is one of a few breaking changes in the Standard Library that I'm
>   aware of (the other major ones are immutable sets, and **2D vector
>   construction**).

Answer can be considered legit with high probability since it is from MS employee that works on implementing STL.

So does anybody knows what exactly he refers to?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8939320/636019

Comment: Provide a link to the Connect issue, or if it's private, at least properly cite the engineer you're quoting.

Comment: Also possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5759232/636019

Comment: @ Ben it is irrelevant imno since it is not about this Q, but : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/691756/std-make-pair-error-in-vc11

Comment: Stephan left his email address in the answer you link to, and invites you to email him if you have any further questions regarding his answer.  He's a nice guy, he won't bite.

Comment: Yeah I know (he is my fav C9 superstar :) ), but he is super busy so I would feel bad interrupting him while he works on implementing STL. :)

Comment: I asked, and he answered immediately. Which was super nice, and also pleasantly surprising, as it was a question on something he wrote a year ago. :) I've copied the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I emailed Stephan and asked what he was talking about. Here's his answer (edited for formatting). It didn't sound like he was planning to post the answer here; if he does, I'll delete this copy.

**Everything from here down is Stephan speaking.**

I was referring to this:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> v(11, 22);
}
```

It compiles with VC10 SP1 (following C++03), but not with VC11 RTM (following C++11): *[snip error message dump]*

**C++03 23.1.1 [lib.sequence.reqmts]/9** said:

> For every sequence defined in this clause and in clause 21:
>   — the constructor
>   `template <class InputIterator> X(InputIterator f, InputIterator l, const Allocator& a = Allocator())`
>  shall have the same effect
>   as:
>   `X(static_cast<typename X::size_type>(f), static_cast<typename X::value_type>(l), a)`
>   if `InputIterator` is an integral type.

This transformed `vector<vector<int>> v(11, 22)` to `vector<vector<int>> v(static_cast<size_t>(11), static_cast<vector<int>>(22))`, which is valid.  (`static_cast` is capable of invoking explicit constructors, like `vector`'s size constructor.)

**C++11 23.2.3 [sequence.reqmts]/14** says:

> For every sequence container defined in this Clause and in Clause 21:
>   — If the constructor
>   `template <class InputIterator> X(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())`
>   is called with a type `InputIterator` that does not qualify as an input iterator, then the constructor shall not participate in overload resolution.

This removes the (InIt, InIt) ctor from overload resolution.  That leaves `(size_type n, const T& value)`, where `T` is `vector<int>`.  However, that would try to implicitly convert `22` to a temporary `vector<int>` (in order to bind it to `const T&`).  The explicitness of `vector`'s size constructor forbids that.

Reading [the other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759232/stdvector-default-construction-c11-and-breaking-changes?lq=1), this is a different issue.

STL