# Why enums can't be used as arguments in this vector constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, stl

This code fragment:

```
enum {N = 10, M = 100};

vector<int> v(N, M);
```

fails to compile with Visual Studio 2013, due to the following error:

> error C2838: 'iterator_category' : illegal qualified name in member declaration

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Both gcc and clang are ok with this, seems like a bug.

Comment: I strongly suspect VS's bug..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bug in both VS2012 and VS2013 since it's not conforming to the C++11 standard (with `_HAS_CPP0X` defined as 1):

C++03 23.1.1 [lib.sequence.reqmts]/9 says:

> For every sequence defined in this clause and in clause 21:
>
> — the constructor
>   `template <class InputIterator> X(InputIterator f, InputIterator l, const Allocator& a = Allocator())` shall have the same effect as:
>
> `X(static_cast<typename X::size_type>(f), static_cast<typename X::value_type>(l), a)` if `InputIterator` is an integral type.

but from C++11 23.2.3 [sequence.reqmts]/14:

> For every sequence container defined in this Clause and in Clause 21:
>
> — If the constructor `template <class InputIterator> X(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())` is called with a type `InputIterator` that does not
>   qualify as an input iterator, **then the constructor shall not participate in overload resolution.**

**That constructor should not have been considered at all**

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12432482/1938163

As a workaround you could "*help the overload resolution a bit*", e.g.

```
std::vector<int> v(static_cast<std::vector<int>::size_type>(N), M);
```

Answer (score 10):

Since C++11 the `vector` constructor accepting two `InputIterators` should be disabled if the two arguments aren't iterators. VS2013 fails to implement this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Visual Studio 2013 bug, from the error being generated (*[see it live](http://rextester.com/FGXRA34045)*), this is just a small portion:

> [...]
>
> see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector>::vector<,void>(_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
>
> [...]>

It is attempting to use the constructor that takes two input iterators. Which would be a bug, both `gcc` and `clang` are fine with this code.

We can that in C++11 [that constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) should not be considered:

> Constructs the container with the contents of the range [first, last). This constructor does not participate in overload resolution if InputIt does not satisfy InputIterator, to avoid ambiguity with the overload 2 (since C++11)

This agrees with the draft C++11 standard section `23.2.3` *Sequence containers* paragraph *14* which says:

> If the constructor
>
> ```
> template <class InputIterator>
> X(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
>   const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())
> ```
>
> is called with a type InputIterator that does not qualify as an input iterator, then the constructor
>   shall not participate in overload resolution.