# C++ Why do vector initialization calls the copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++03

When you initialize a vector in the following way:

```
std::vector<MyClass> MyVec(10);
```

It calls the default constructor once and then calls the copy constructor an additional 10 times.
So, if I understand it correctly, the objects in the vector are all made by the copy constructor.

Can someone explain the reason for calling the copy constructor and not the default one?
Or even just allocating the memory without the objects?

Comment: RE allocating memory without constructing object: Then you can't actually use it. Even the assignment operator may require something the constructors establish. Of course, just reserving could also make sense, but it would have very different semantics.

Comment: [My test](http://liveworkspace.org/code/b831cffa5df38a6b12c8a637de815573) shows the default constructor being called ten times.

Comment: This behaviour has changed in C++11, where value-initialization of each member is possible.

Comment: @chris that's because this was changed in C++11.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8939320

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will allocate memory without objects, except that you've specified an initial size of 10, so it *has* to create 10 objects. If you want memory for 10 objects without actually creating them, you can do something like:

```
 std::vector<MyClass> MyVec;
 MyVec.reserve(10);
```

If you look the signature of the constructor you're using is something like:

```
vector(size_t num, T initial_value = T());
```

That let's you pass a value to use to fill the spots you tell it to create. If you don't specify a value, it creates one (with the default ctor) to pass to the ctor, and then makes copies of that in the vector itself.

There's no real question that it *could* do other things, but that provides a reasonable balance between simplicity (don't specify a value), versatility (specify a value if you want), and code size (avoid duplicating the entire ctor just to default construct the contents).

Comment: Actually signature is `explicit vector(size_type count)`, so "seed" default value is created inside.

Comment: @Rost, From looking, it seems it was changed to that in C++11. The question is technically a C++03 case, as I found out a minute ago.

Comment: It is a matter of C++03 vs C++11. In C++03, you have `vector(size_t count, T const & value = T())` and in C++11, you have `vector(size_t count)` and `vector(size_t count, T const & value)` . Notice the difference.

Comment: @chris Indeed, previous was with default parameter